# I couldn't find the flow sensor datasheet

Tags: components

I want to know whether it is working.I want to know the VCC GND and the data terminals.what do I have to do to get 300mV out of here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the marking for Allegro's 3-pin SIP components is an A followed by the last three digits of device part number, I think the component your looking for is the **A3142E**, package UA.

Datasheet: https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A3141-2-3-4-Datasheet.ashx

Answer (score 0):

They look like Hall sensors, perhaps arranged with something (not shown) such as a paddle wheel with magnets embedded, in order to deliver a digital quadrature output.

You would use the pulses and their phase relationship to determine the flow rate and direction, and over some range of flow rates you will have a known relationship and uncertainty.

It sounds like you want an analog signal related to flow, which may be  possible to get using a frequency-to-voltage converter circuit (typically something like a one-shot multivibrator and a low-pass filter) but making it bidirectional would be a bit more complex.